# Setting expireAfterSeconds on index for ttl not working in documentDb 4.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aws-documentdb

I am trying to make an exclusive lock semaphore using mongoose on a documentDb collection document.
The index and document gets created alright, however the document never expire. I've tried turning createdAt into a string and set it to an ISO string, to no avail. Any ideas how to get ttl to work in documentDb 4.0? I can delete the document when I am done, however I want to automatically clear this in case the executed script dies holding the lock.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = require("mongoose");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const whoAmI = uuidv4();

(async () => {

  await mongoose.connect(connectionString);

  const LockSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    owner: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
  });

  LockSchema.index( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30 } )

  const Lock = mongoose.model("migration", LockSchema, "locks");

  result = await Lock.findOneAndUpdate({id: "lock"}, { $setOnInsert: { owner: whoAmI}}, { upsert: true, new: true}).lean();
  if (result?.owner === whoAmI) {
    await exec("<something>", async (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      mongoose.disconnect();
      if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
      }
      if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log("done...")
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: you found any solution yet? i facing the same problem.

using this index on a mongoDB worked fine for me:
`SecretSchema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });`

with this i could set the expireAt time to a custom time using the "expireAt" field.
But when i use this mongoose Index on a AWS documentDB, it does not delete any documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTL Index property currently is not available to DocDB Elastic Cluster.

Check the DocDB type you are using to be sure that isn't the problem. I was using DocDB 5.0 but it was the Elastic version, this could have saved me a lot of time.

You can check the docs with the available features [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-index-properties):

| Command | 3.6 | 4.0 | 5.0 | Elastic cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TTL | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |
| Unique | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Partial | No | No | No | No |
| Case Insensitive | No | No | No | No |
| Sparse | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |
| Background | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |

Answer (score 0):

Is the TTL index actually created? You can check if you connect with mongosh or mongo shell and run the command on the collection: `db.collection_name.getIndexes()` .
Enable Mongoose debug to see more:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

Not sure which Mongoose version you're using, but try to explicitly enable auto indexing:

```
const LockSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    owner: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
  },
 { autoIndex: true }
);
```